# Unexpected output on re-assigning an object-reference

Tags: java, oop, object-reference

I am learning OOP, and got some assignment on making object-references and checking results. I got a `Book` class and a `BookTest` class, where in the `BookTest` class I make 4 object references to the `Book` object.

A `Book` has a name, and a function to get that name of that book.

```
class Book {
    private String name;

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

The references to the `Book` object looks like this:

```
Book b1 = new Book("The story of ...");
Book b2 = b1;
Book b3 = new Book("Second story");
Book b4 = new Book("Third story");
```

This all works great, whenever I print out `b2.getName()` I get the expected `"The story of ..."` string.

But whenever I add this this line before the printing of `b2.getName()` line:

```
b1 = b3;
```

I expected `b2.getName()` to be `"Second story"`, because `b1` has been assigned to `b3`. It is in-fact still the `"The story of ..."` string.

Why is this?

Comment: b1 has been assigned to the Book object that b3 points to. But b2 has not been assigned anything new...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Book b1 = new Book("The story of ...");
Book b2 = b1;
Book b3 = new Book("Second story");
Book b4 = new Book("Third story");
```

[image]

After `b1 = b3;` the b1 reference goes to the b3 but not the b2.

[image]

I hope this helpful to understand.

Comment: Thanks for this, but can you explain the process why `b2` stays on the `b1`?

Comment: because you were doing is change the object reference 'b1' to 'b3'. it doesn't affected to the 'b2'. If you want change the 'b2'. you have to define    'b2 = b3' that means the 'b2' reference also point to the 'b3' value.

Comment: Alright, but why doesn't this rule apply to the `b2 = b1` assignment then? It's kind of confusing right now.

Answer (score 0):

You are understanding wrong.

If you do:

```
b2=b1;
```

And then:

```
b1=b3;
```

`b2` is still with the former reference of `b1`:

```
Book b1 = new Book("The story of ...");
```